# Objects moving towards center of world rather than following way points?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I keep having 3d models and even Unity built in 3d objects gravitate towards the center of the world. Im unsure if it's based on my script using Vector 3. Can anyone please help me. Even if I move the waypoints up in the air the 3d objects ignore the points and slowly gravitate towards the center. Im also doing fishing game so this is my AI for fish behavior.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Simple_AI_patrol : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] wayPoints;
    public float speed;
    public int currentPoint;
    public bool doPatrol = true;
    Vector3 velocity;
    Vector3 moveDirection;
    Vector3 target;
    Rigidbody rb;


    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }


    void Update () {
            if(currentPoint < wayPoints.Length){
                target = wayPoints [currentPoint].position;
                moveDirection = target - transform.position;
                velocity = rb.velocity;

                if(moveDirection.magnitude < 1){
                    currentPoint = Random.Range (0, wayPoints.Length);// or currentPoint++
                }else{
                    velocity = moveDirection.normalized * speed;
                }
            }else{
                if(doPatrol){
                    currentPoint = 0;
                }else{
                    velocity = Vector3.zero;
                }
            }
            rb.velocity = velocity;
            transform.LookAt (target);
        }
}
```

Comment: first, you should only manipulate rigid bodies in `fixedUpdate()`, it might just be a miscalculation because of that; update it, and report back ;)

Comment: also please include the `usings` in the code; you might be using the "wrong" `Random` class, that can cause misbehaviours too

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I looked up fixed update so it makes more sense. Yet the models still gravitate towards the center. All they have is a rigid body. They swim freely but once they get to the center they stay stuck with minimal room to move.

Comment: I'm not that of an expert on this topic, but this guy certainly is, this video exactly demonstrates what you want to achieve (I think) Have fun: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUdx_Nj4Xk0

Comment: I fixed it thank you so much!